# Removing duplicates efficiently and with a low memory overhead

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, sorting

I want to filter efficiently a list of integers for duplicates in a way that only the resulting set needs to be stored.

One way this can be seen:

- we have a range of integers $S = \{1, \dots{}, N\}$ with $N$ big (say $2^{40}$)
- we have a function $f : S \to S$ with, supposedly, many collisions (the images are uniformly distributed in $S$)
- we then need to store $f[S]$, that is $\{f(x) | x \in S\}$

I have a quite accurate (probabilistic) estimation of what $|f[S]|$ is, and can therefore allocate data structures in advance (say $|f[S]| \approx 2^{30}$).

I have had a few ideas, but I am not sure what would be the best approach:

- a bitset is out of the question because the input set does not fit into memory.
- a hash table, but (1) it requires some memory overhead, say 150% of $|f[S]|$ and (2) the table has to be explored when built which requires additional time because of the memory overhead.
- an "on the fly" sort, preferably with $O(N)$ complexity (non-comparison sort). Regarding that, I am not sure what is the major difference between [bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) and [flashsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flashsort).
- a simple array with a binary search tree, but this requires $O(N \log |f[S]|)$ time.
- maybe using [Bloom filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) or a similar data structure could be useful in a relaxation (with false positives) of the problem.

Some questions on stackoverflow seem to tackle with this sort of things (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240997/sorting-array-in-on-run-time, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951547/java-array-finding-duplicates), but none seems to match my requirements.

Comment: Do you need to enumerate f[S] (whatever it is), or to be able to tell quickly whether some x is in it?

Comment: @Gilles: I believe that, since no obvious structure can be found in f[S], the two solutions are equivalent.

Comment: Your numbers don't add up. The expected image of a random function on a domain of size $N$ is roughly $(1-1/e)N$. Another issue is that going through $2^{56}$ is going to take too long unless you have a supercomputer or a large cluster at your disposal.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus: Thanks for your comment! Nevermind the figures, they are hypothetical. I do not restrict $f$ to be a PRF, and its image can be anything (say f could be just a truncation to the last 30 bits). Your comment on the image size is interesting though, where does this result come from ?

Comment: @doc The expected image size is, as they say, "well-known". The probability that $x \in [N]$ appears in the image is $1-(1-1/N)^N \sim 1-1/e$.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus: Ok, thank you. But as I said, I think this is specific to random functions and in this case $f$ is not.

Comment: Why was this migrated? Sure he's described the problem fairly generically, but he has said he's implementing in C? (And I have now checked, so I know the direct answer is "because it was suggested to migrate...")

Comment: The time for the binary search tree would be $O(N \log |f[S]|)$, which may or may not be close to $O(N\log N)$ in practice but still is more accurate.

Comment: Interesting insight, thank you for your comment.

Comment: With $N \sim 2^{56}$, won't a linear time algorithm be prohibitive too? (From my calculations, even if you consider one element of $S$ in 1 nano-second, it would take you a good 2 years!).

Comment: The figures are hypothetical, and probably indeed do not make sense on a single computer. I will reduce them slightly to avoid confusion.

Comment: Hmm could you elaborate ? The number of duplicates is simply $N-|f[S]|$ I guess. The use of bloom filters implies false positives, and thus also for values in $f[S]$. Moreover, I think the resulting structure would require a $O(N)$ procedure to be enumerated (rather than $O(|f[S]|)$).

Comment: As commented above, the size of the image is $(1-1/e)N$. So at most you can save this factor $e/(e-1)$. However, I'm not sure how exactly you'll store the image set. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Do you want to be able to answer questions of the form "is $x$ in the image"?

Comment: The size of the image is $N(1-1/e)$ on average for _random functions_. In this case, $f$ is not a random function and the size of its image is smaller. Consider for instance $f(x) = x \bmod{100}$, the size of the image is $100$. Of course, then then problem makes no sense and in my case, $f$ is more complicated than that. I would like the image stored in some collection that is easy to run through afterwards.

Comment: I would go for the hash table, the overhead seems reasonable and it will run quickly. In what way is the hash table solution suboptimal for you?

Comment: @doc do you have any probabilistic knowledge about the structure of the image, or is it just the size?

Comment: Just the size. I can assume the the elements of $f[S]$ are "uniformly distributed" in $S$. The hash table is probably the way to go, but I am disappointed with the memory overhead, and this problem intuitively seems to be likely to have a better solution...

Answer (score 1):

Why not bin and chain?

The idea is to store positive integers representable by $n = k+m$ bits in an array $A$ of $2^k$ entries representing ranges of values: entry $A[y]$, $y \ge 0$, represents the range $[2^m y, 2^m(y+1)-1]$.  For any $1 \le x \lt 2^n$ we may write $x = 2^m y + z$ where $y$ has $k$ bits and $z$ has $m$ bits.  Try to store $z$ (not $x$!) at location $y$:

- When $A[y]=z$ already, do nothing: $x$ is a duplicate.
- When $A[y]$ is uninitialized, store $z$ at $A[y]$.
- Otherwise, store an index into a separate array used to chain the $z$'s (which have collided at $y$) in linked lists.  You will have to search linearly through the list headed by $A[y]$ and, depending on what the search uncovers, potentially insert $z$ into the list.

At the end, $f(S)$ is easy to recover by looping through the initialized entries of $A$ and--by merely concatenating two bitstrings--reassembling each $z$ found at location $y$ (either directly or within a chain referenced there) into the original value $x = 2^m y + z$.

When the distribution is close to uniform and $2^k$ exceeds $N$, there will not be much chaining (this can be assessed in the usual ways) and the chains will tend to be short.  When the distribution is nonuniform, the algorithm still works, but can reach quadratic timing.  If that's a possibility, use something more efficient than chains (and pay a little overhead for storage).

The storage needed is at most $2^n$ bits for $A$ and $2^{2k}$ bits for the chains (assuming $m \le k$).  This is exactly the space needed to store $2^k$ values of $n$ bits each. If you're confident in the uniformity, you can underallocate the storage for the chains. If nonuniformity is a possibility, you may want to increase $k$ and fully advocate the chain storage.

An alternative way of thinking about this solution is that it *is* a hash table with a particularly nice hash function (take the $k$ most significant bits) and, because of that, we only need to store the least significant $m=n-k$ bits in the table.

There are ways to overlay storage for the chains with the storage for $A$ but it doesn't seem worth the bother, because it wouldn't save much (assuming $m$ is much smaller than $k$) space and would make the code harder to develop, debug, and maintain.

Comment: I think the second-to-last paragraph is the central one here, and should probably be at the top (as idea). I don't know the term "bin and chain" (although it makes sense after reading the post). This idea can be extended to [tries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Comment: So, this is $\Theta(n^2)$ on poorly-distributed inputs. I don't see how this is efficient.

Comment: @einpoklum This answer explicitly describes the conditions in which the solution is efficient.